# Zero-Inflated Poisson Distribution (pzipois) in Python?

Tags: r, python, poisson-distribution

I am wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction for the Python version of this package?

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VGAM/versions/1.1-1/topics/Zipois

Specifically, I am looking to use `pzipois` which is the distribution function.

Answer (score 4):

[statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) Python module has probably all functions which you need and more others, see e.g. the section “Discrete and Count Models” in its [API documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api.html):

[image]

Comment: Its not clear that sm.ZeroInflatedPoisson replicates `pzipois` given the differences in the expected inputs.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to be close:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
poisson.cdf(arr, mu)
```